# Translate (and scale) AnatomyData in three-dimensions

Tags: graphics3d, curated-data, geometric-transform, anatomy

I would like to create a `Graphics3D` entity consisting of a human eyeball and a complex figure defined elsewhere. 
 (For a minimal working example, assume that the other object is a `Sphere[]`.)  I need to adjust (transform) the position of the eyeball (not of the other components).

Creating the eyeball is straightforward:

```
eyeball = 
 Show[
 Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "RightEyeball"]["Graphics3D"],
  ViewPoint -> {-1, -.6, 0}]
```

[image: eyeball]

I can put the eyeball and sphere in the same `Graphics3D` by:

```
Show[eyeball, Graphics3D[Sphere[]]]
```

Alas, they do not have the proper relative positions (of course).

I can also simply translate the `Sphere`.

But because my full graphics has lots of components that are carefully arranged, I need to translate *just the eyeball*.  I have tried all manner of

```
Graphics3D[GeometricTransformation[eyeball,
  TranslationTransform[{5, 5, 5}]]]
```

and so forth, without success.

How can I move (in three dimensions) the eyeball to place it wherever I want in a large, complex `Graphics3D` environment that contains other elements?

Comment: for translation you can use `Graphics3D[GeometricTransformation[Sphere[], TranslationTransform[Mean/@PlotRange[eyeball]]]]`.

Comment: @kglr:  That's useful--and *close*--but not quite what I need.  I do *not* want to translate the `Sphere`, as I mentioned.  There must be some way to translate just the eyeball.  Instead, I merely want to translate the eyeball.  Moreover, I do not want to translate it to the mean of the other object... it has to be set at a very special position.

Comment: how about `Graphics3D[{GeometricTransformation[eyeball[[1]], RescalingTransform[PlotRange@eyeball, {{-1,
1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]]}, Axes->True]`?

Comment: @kglr:  Nope.  You've *rescaled* the eyeball, but not *translated* it.  There must be something about the internal representation of the AnatomyData the prevents the objects from being translated...  no?

Comment: David, `RescalingTransform` does _both_ translation and scaling: _"Rescaling transformation is a composition of scaling and translation"_. More generally, you can use `RescalingTransform[PlotRange@eyeball, PlotRange[Graphics3D[Sphere[]]]]]` (replace `Sphere[]` with your 3D primitives).

Comment: @kglr:  That's helpful, but I will want to place the eyeball at a very specific position (within a ray-tracing diagram produced by *LensLab* from *OpticaSoftware*) and the conflation of scaling and translation will be a nightmare!  (Another problem:  I need to orient the eye within the ray-tracing diagram, to see the proper rays.)  All these problems seem to be based on the fact that AnatomyData simply doesn't produce a "traditional" Graphics3D object that can be translated... right?

Comment: I don't think there is anything special about the structure of `eyeball` that prevents geometric transformations. (If you inspect `eyeball[[1]]` it is just a collection of standard directives and primitives.)  Fora example, `TranslationTransform[{x0,y0,z0} -(Mean/@PlotRange[eyeball])]` should translate `eyeball[[1]]`  to the point `{x0,y0,z0}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
GeometricTransformation[eyeball[[1]], 
   TranslationTransform[{x0, y0, z0} - Mean /@ (PlotRange @ eyeball) ]]
```

to translate the center of `eyeball` to `{x0, y0, z0}`.

```
Manipulate[Graphics3D[{{Red, Sphere[]}, PointSize[Large], Point[{x0, y0, z0}], 
   Opacity[.2],
   GeometricTransformation[eyeball[[1]], 
      TranslationTransform[{x0, y0, z0} - Mean /@ (PlotRange @ eyeball) ]]},
  Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {x0, y0, z0}, ImageSize -> 400],
 {{x0, -5}, -10, 10, LabeledSlider},
 {{y0, 7}, -10, 10, LabeledSlider},
 {{z0, -3}, -10, 10, LabeledSlider}]
```

[image]

Comment: There.  Thanks.  ($\checkmark$)